# Import settings from Habit Browser

Tags: settings, browser

I'm trying to import settings for [Habit Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.pigsty.HabitBrowser). After navigating to Settings -> Advanced -> Import Settings, I get:

```
0
../
```

How can I change the location to the Download folder? Alternatively, what's the `../`? - So that I could move my backup file to that location?

Answer (score 1):

Storage access permission should be granted manually.

Many thanks to [user Hardon from Android Forums](https://androidforums.com/threads/import-settings-from-habit-browser.1336288/#post-8036500).

> OK, I think I see what it's doing, and I might have a guess at what your problem was. Have you granted it storage access permission? Without that it cannot see any of your directories, and because it's an old app (not updated for 4 years) it doesn't know how to request that permission from a modern Android version. So you need to go into Settings > Apps > Habit > Permissions and grant it storage access. I think that should fix it for you (it did for me).